# How to validate solr query syntax using standard query parser

Tags: solr, solrj

I am using solr 8.2 version. Here, I am passing the below queries in solr dashboard query screen. e.g

select * xyz 
delete * xyz
xyz * abc.

Solr return all results with the above queries. I want to understand how solr is parsing it internally. 
and returning all records?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The essential tool for debugging search results is the “explain” mechanism of Solr which is triggered by adding `&debug=true` to search queries. This produces detail scoring information for each document.

The `debug` parameter can be specified multiple times and supports the following arguments:

`debug=query:` return debug information about the query only.

`debug=timing:` return debug information about how long the query took to process.

`debug=results:` return debug information about the score results (also known as "explain").

By default, score explanations are returned as large string values, using newlines and tab indenting for structure & readability, but an additional debug.explain.structured=true parameter may be specified to return this information as nested data structures native to the response format requested by wt.

`debug=all:` return all available debug information about the request request.

You could also use the analysis tool in solr. Go to the admin and click analysis.

There is Solr Query Debugger extension available for crome browser. This will help to modify, execute and explain solr queries.
Its available here : [Solr Query Debugger](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/solr-query-debugger/gmpkeiamnmccifccnbfljffkcnacmmdl?hl=en)

[image: Image of extension]

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @abhijit.

Comment: I want to restrict invalid query parameters. is there any functionality in solr to acheive this?

Comment: .what is invalid query parameters for you...?

Comment: If I pass *:* it returns all records which are standard working of solr. instead of this, passing any literals with  *(asterisk) like I mentioned in the description, also retrieves all records.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. I think, it is a default behaviour of solr standard query parser.